# Indexing failure/odd behaviour with array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, indexing

I have some code that is intended to convert a 3-dimensional list to an array. Technically it works in that I get a 3-dimensional array, but indexing only works when I don't iterate accross one of the dimensions, and doesn't work if I do.

Indexing works here:

```
listTempAllDays = []
for j in listGPSDays:
    listTempDay = []
    for i in listGPSDays[0]:
        arrayDay = np.array(i)
        listTempDay.append(arrayDay)
    arrayTemp = np.array(listTempDay)
    listTempAllDays.append(arrayTemp)

arrayGPSDays = np.array(listTempAllDays)
print(arrayGPSDays[0,0,0])
```

It doesn't work here:

```
listTempAllDays = []
for j in listGPSDays:
    listTempDay = []
    for i in j:
        arrayDay = np.array(i)
        listTempDay.append(arrayDay)
    arrayTemp = np.array(listTempDay)
    listTempAllDays.append(arrayTemp)

arrayGPSDays = np.array(listTempAllDays)
print(arrayGPSDays[0,0,0])
```

The difference between the two pieces of code is in the inner for loop. The first piece of code also works for all elements in `listGPSDays` (e.g. `for i in listGPSDays[1]:` etc...).

Removing the final print call allows the code to run in the second case, or changing the final line to `print(arrayGPSDays[0][0,0])` does also run.

In both cases checking the type at all levels returns `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

I would like this array indexing to work, if possible - what am I missing?

**The following is provided as example data:**

Anonymised results from `print(arrayGPSDays[0:2,0:2,0:2])`, generated using the first piece of code (so that the indexing works! - but also resulting in `arrayGPSDays[0]` being the same as `arrayGPSDays[1]`):

```
    [[['1' '2']
      ['3' '4']]

     [['1' '2']
      ['3' '4']]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy`'s `array` constructor can handle arbitrarily dimensioned iterables. They only stipulation is that they can't be jagged (i.e. each "row" in each dimension must have the same length).

Here's an example:

```
In [1]: list_3d = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h',  'i'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]]

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: np.array(list_3d)
Out[3]: 
array([[['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f']],

       [['g', 'h', 'i'],
        ['j', 'k', 'l']]], dtype='<U1')

In [4]: array_3d = np.array(list_3d)

In [5]: array_3d[0,0,0]
Out[5]: 'a'

In [6]: array_3d.shape
Out[6]: (2, 2, 3)
```

If the array *is* jagged, `numpy` will "squash" down to the dimension where the jagged-ness happens. Since that explanation is clear as mud, an example might help:

```
In [20]: jagged_3d = [ [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']] ]

In [21]: jagged_arr = np.array(jagged_3d)

In [22]: jagged_arr.shape
Out[22]: (2,)

In [23]: jagged_arr
Out[23]: 
array([list([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]),
       list([['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']])], dtype=object)
```

The reason the constructor isn't working out of the box is because you have a jagged array. `numpy` simply does not support jagged arrays due to the fact that each `numpy` array has a well-defined `shape` representing the length of each dimension. So if the items in a given dimension are different lengths, this abstraction falls apart, and `numpy` simply doesn't allow it.

HTH.

Comment: @Isaac I agree that a warning might be nice. However it's `numpy` that is having the issue, not Python ;).

Comment: @Isaac well if you think no warning is bad, imagine if it actually mucked with your data without you knowing...besides, how would `numpy` know *where* to pad? Or what *value* to use? `numpy` might ruin the semantics of the given data by padding incorrectly. `numpy` is heavily used by the scientific community: A lot of math routines are used in `numpy` (i.e. jagged arrays make no sense in linear algebra), and so it makes sense why `numpy` won't allow jagged arrays and why it won't automatically pad. I think `numpy`s behavior is actually reasonable: but a warning would be good.

Comment: @Isaac Furthermore, the data isn't actually lost (see example above). It's just that `numpy` explicitly keeps the data in a different format (i.e. it's a `numpy` array with two objects: each object is a `list` with different lengths)

Answer (score 0):

So Isaac, it seems your code have some syntax misinterpretations,

In your `for` statement, `j` represents an ITEM inside the list `listGPSDays` (I assume it is a list), not the ITEM INDEX inside the list, and you don't need to "get" the range of the list, python can do it for yourself, try:

```
for j in listGPSdays:
```

instead of

```
for j in range(len(listGPSDays)):
```

Also, try changing this line of code from:

```
for i in listGPSDays[j]:
```

to:

```
for i in listGPSDays.index(j):
```

I think it will solve your problem, hope it works!

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it did help me improve my question, and simplify my code - thank you.